# Determining if a printer can handle a print job without look-up

Tags: java, performance, printing

I have been battling the `PrintServiceLookup`; the `lookupPrintServices(DocFlavor flavor, AttributeSet attributes)` method is excessively slow to detect printers in our application with the initial run-in. Clients with more than 100 network printers have reported that behaviour that executes this code is poorly performing the first time it is run.

After seeing that the look-up results are being cached, I have initially deployed a dummy look-up within a separate thread (executed at start-up). However, for a particular client this solution is not working.

I do not currently have their environment and cannot see what is causing the exact performance problem.

I am trying to see if a `PrintService` supports a given `MediaSizeName` **without** performing a look-up of `DocFlavor` and `AttributeSet`. So I pull all available `PrintService`s and the default `PrintService`:

```
private static final PrintService[] PRINTSERVICES = 
   PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);

private static final PrintService DEFAULTSERVICE = 
   PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
```

And then, obtain the `PrintService` and the `MediaSizeName` from the client request. Finally, I ask the `PrintService` if the `MediaSizeName` is supported by:

```
private void checkPrintServiceForMediaSize(PrintService pservice) throws MediaSizeNotSupportedException{
     if(!pservice.isAttributeValueSupported(_mediaSizeName,null,null))
            throw new MediaSizeNotSupportedException("This media size is not supported by the selected printer.");
     }
```

The [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/print/PrintService.html#isAttributeValueSupported%28javax.print.attribute.Attribute,%20javax.print.DocFlavor,%20javax.print.attribute.AttributeSet%29) declares that when `isAttributeValueSupported(Attribute attrval,DocFlavor flavor,AttributeSet attributes)` is called with null `DocFlavor` and `AttributeSet`

> this method tells whether this Print Service supports the given printing attribute value for some possible combination of doc flavor and set of attributes

and has behaved correctly up until now. However, I am not entirely sure if this is the way to perform if a printer supports a selected page size.

I would appreciate your feedback and experience on this issue.

---

**Update**

Around the time I implemented my approach, my workstation decided to have serious network issues, which took me awhile to figure out. Finally, my implementation has been tested with the networking tool [SoftPerfect Connection Emulator](http://www.softperfect.com/products/connectionemulator/) (to simulate network load) and the results have not improved significantly.

I will continue testing and update this question. Hopefully I can find a solution and share it with people here. I am guessing that the initial lookup:

```
private static final PrintService[] PRINTSERVICES = 
   PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
```

is still causing issues.

---

**Update 2**

The beta build is finally tested on the client environment and performance of the printing dialog is about 5 times improved (the initial pull of printer now takes about 1 minute under the same environment compared to about 5 minutes). Still the initial wait time is not an acceptable amount of time, however, is the best I could do for now. We have also heard from the client that a print server is being used and following the suggestions in the comments (@Wardy), I will be moving on in this direction. Hopefully, we can leverage the advantages of the print server.

Comment: Can you do the actual lookup in a separate thread on startup?

Comment: @eabraham as I mentioned there's a dummy lookup performed at startup. All subsequent lookups being performed depend on user input.

Comment: Have you profiled to see where the time is spent?  My guess is that a lot of time is spent on host name lookups of various kinds combined with a bad DNS-server entry.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I have used [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html). However, in my own dev environment I have no issues.
Good guess though, something I haven't considered. Although the client is reporting that other software has no issues. On the other hand, other software do not perform lookups per paper size selection; they just send it through to the printer and let it handle the situation.

Comment: Windows applications can do lookups in WINS.  Java applications cannot do that.  This mean that more needs to be in place for this to work.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen do you mind elaborating a little? You mean that they actually perform look-ups? I have confirmed that Microsoft Office products do not filter printers based on paper size.

Comment: I think of the information gathering.  Can you do some profiling on the troublesome computers?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen unfortunately not. It is not a possibility at the moment. There's definitely load on the network, however, the extra/unwanted look-ups are causing the issues.

Comment: From what i understand about printers ... you have a print server ... surely the print server should have maybe a webservice endpoint or something that can regularly "poll" to check these things then cache the results. Then your app could simply make a web service call could it not? (thus farming the time consuming bit out)

Comment: @Wardy We are verifying if there is a print server in place. From my search using [google](https://www.google.ca/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=java+print+server+printer+lookup#hl=en&sa=X&ei=3_qGT9uOCMHu0gH917XEBw&sqi=2&ved=0CBkQvwUoAQ&q=java+%22print+server%22+web+service&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=db75979cae857fbe&biw=1520&bih=989) and [hp](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/ePrint-Print-Apps-Mobile/Enable-Disable-Web-Services-on-your-printer/td-p/572623) I understand that this is possible, although, I haven't been able to see common practices and API. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you able to have a central "server" that can run on the network (that you can implement), or is this a standalone client that is installed on each workstation?

Comment: @Deco both are possible, however, in this case the client is invoked through [javaws](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview-137531.html) and is located at a central server.

Comment: can't you solve this by a simple portscan? So you can discover printers in the network, and could asume that they will be able to print.

Answer (score 2):

More aggressive caching. Have the client perform the look-up once and persist the cache between restarts. Better yet, save the cache to a central data store which is accessible by all clients.

I'm assuming that network printers and their capabilities don't change that often but you have to update the cache eventually, but the "who" and "when" is dependent on your environment.

Updates to the cache can be made by a client that runs your current discovery in the background and if changes are detected updates the cache. If you have a central component that runs continuously anyway, that would be a good place where you can check in fixed intervals.

If you have some kind of directory service you can compare its list of printers with you cache before contacting each printer to get its capabilities to lessen network and cpu load.

Comment: I'm not sure if aggressive caching of MediaSizeName is possible due to http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6278300

Answer (score 0):

If list of printers is stored in LDAP, you may try to lookup printers using [LDAP](http://wiki.java.net/twiki/bin/view/Javapedia/LDAP).